# GET request returns index.html doc instead of json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

After deploying my mern app to Heroku, the `GET` request on the home page `('http://localhost:8000/post/')` is now returning `index.html` instead of `json data` from the request. I'm getting `200 status` code but the response is `html`. However, it works fine locally.
All the other requests are working except this one.
Whenever I think I've fixed it, Heroku displays the json data instead of the UI on this same route. I'm assuming that these issues are related.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

route/controller - list posts

```
router.get('/', (list)) 

exports.list = (req, res) => {
  const sort = { title: 1 };
  Post.find()
    .sort(sort)
    .then((posts) => res.json(posts))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
};
```

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

// import routes
...
const app = express();

// connect db - first arg is url (specified in .env)
const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI 
mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
});
mongoose.connection
  .once("open", function () {
    console.log("DB Connected!");
  })
  .on("error", function (error) {
    console.log("Error is: ", error);
  });

// middlewares
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});

// middleware
...
//  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')))
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use('/post', postRoutes);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

ListPosts.js

```
class ListPosts extends React.Component {
    state = {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        date: '',
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getPosts()
    }

   getPosts = () => {
        axios.get(`${API}/post`)
        .then((response) => {
            const data = response.data
            this.setState({posts: [data]})
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
     
    displayPosts = (posts) => {
        if (!posts.length) return null;
      posts.map((post, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
           ...
            </div>    
        ))
    }


    render() {
        return (
         <div>
           {this.displayPosts(this.state.posts)}
           </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListPosts
```

Comment: Where is you API ? Seems like you are sending `axios` request to the same server which serve React code.

Comment: The API is on http://localhost:8000 and so the react app is on port 8001 @Dilshan

Comment: Can you add the `axios` request object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some of the answers already mentioned seperating your API and client routes and found the exact issue, I would like to just add a little bit of recommendations based on my experience with serving your react app using `express`. (Trick is to also add versioning)

```js
app.use('/api/v1/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/post', postRoutes);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {  
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
    app.get("/*", (_, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Your request `'http://localhost:8000/'` matches two route handler

```
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});
```

---

```
router.get('/', (list))
```

Since your **client build** route is placed above the **list** route it will always return the index.html because precedence matters in express when defining routes.

A good practice and solution is to always differentiate your api routes from the static ones by appending `/api` before all routes as below

```
app.use('api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('api/post', postRoutes);
app.use('api/user', userRoutes);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your current implementation you have 2 app.get for the same path -> '/'
So, express responds with the first one. Which  right now is:

```
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});
```

You can either, specify a different path

```
app.use("/post", postRoutes);
```

or rearrange the sequence.

```
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(postRoutes);

app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});
```

or change the controller

```
app.post('/' ...) // instead of app.get('/'...)
```

You need to specify the routes url or avoid two 'app.get' for the same route. If you want you can also change the controller from 'app.get' to 'app.post' and express will deem them different. But, if both are app.get for the same route, the first one will send the response and the second one will never be called.

What you can do is, first try to re-arrange the sequence. If it works and that is indeed the problem, don't stick with it as a solution. It's the wrong way to go about. Instead, give your routes a different url or change the controller from 'app.get' to 'app.post'

Answer (score 2):

```
router.get('/', (list)) 

const list = (req, res) => {
  const sort = { title: 1 };
  Post.find()
    .sort(sort)
    //  .limit(10)
    .then((posts) => res.json(posts))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
};    
module.exports = router;
```

In server.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

....

app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(postRoutes);
```

You need to update like this.

It's just sequence problem in express middlewares. You have updated middlewares about get method(/*). So it's always returning index.html instead of JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this but unfortunately it's still responding with index.html. @NattawutPornpetcharat

Comment: module.exports = router; Have you updated like this on route? Can you post more code about postRoutes?

Comment: Yes, I already had an export statement in the route file. I just hadn't added it to my code on SO.  All my other routes work fine, it's just this one that's returning html. @NattawutPornpetcharat

Comment: @Rahni, are you getting the index.html file in your public folder by chance??

Answer (score 0):

You can change `const port = process.env.PORT || 80;` line without 80 port. its worked for me `const port = process.env.PORT;`